# Adjusted time returned by Date function

Tags: javascript

Im converting a date and time string to a Date object:

```
var timestamp = "2013-05-02T07:18:37";
var toDate = new Date(timestamp);

console.log('timestamp is: ' + timestamp);
console.log('toDate is ' + toDate);
```

I get the result:

```
timestamp is: 2013-05-02T07:18:37 
toDate is: Thu May 02 2013 08:18:37 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

As you can see, the time is adjusted by 1 hour. Im testing in Chrome on windows 7. I do not want to time adjusted by 1 huor. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Call [**`toUTCString`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) explicitly:

```
console.log('toDate is ' + toDate.toUTCString());
```

The [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) says about `toString` (which is implicitly called when you just use `toDate`) (emphasis mine):

> The contents of the String are **implementation-dependent**, but are **intended to represent the Date in the current time zone** in a convenient, human-readable form.